# order strings according to some characters

Tags: r, string, sorting

I have a vector of strings, each of those has a number inside and I like to sort this vector according to this number.

MWE:

```
> str = paste0('N', sample(c(1,2,5,10,11,20), 6, replace = FALSE), 'someotherstring')
> str
[1] "N11someotherstring" "N5someotherstring"  "N2someotherstring"  "N20someotherstring" "N10someotherstring" "N1someotherstring" 
> sort(str)
[1] "N10someotherstring" "N11someotherstring" "N1someotherstring"  "N20someotherstring" "N2someotherstring"  "N5someotherstring"
```

while I'd like to have

```
[1] "N1someotherstring"  "N2someotherstring"  "N5someotherstring"  "N10someotherstring" "N11someotherstring" "N20someotherstring"
```

I have thought of using something like:

```
num = sapply(strsplit(str, split = NULL), function(s) {
  as.numeric(paste0(head(s, -15)[-1], collapse = ""))
})
str = str[sort(num, index.return=TRUE)$ix]
```

but I guess there might be something simpler

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an easy way to do this via `gtools` package,

```
gtools::mixedsort(str)
#[1] "N1someotherstring"  "N2someotherstring"  "N5someotherstring"  "N10someotherstring" "N11someotherstring" "N20someotherstring"
```

Comment: looking for other string manipulation, I just got another trick : `ind = sort(as.numeric(gsub('[A-Z,a-z]', '', str)), index.return=TRUE)`

Comment: @clemlaflemme yes there are quite a few ways you can do this.